# Stacks in arithmetic geometry

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Stacks, of varying kinds, appear in algebraic geometry whenever we have moduli problems, most famously the stacks of (marked) curves. But these seem to be to be very geometric in motivation, so I was wondering if there are natural examples of stacks that arise in arithmetic geometry or number theory.

EDIT: the question is [now at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96957/stacks-in-modern-number-theory-arithmetic-geometry).

Comment: This seems like it would be a better question for MO.

Comment: Heh, I was thinking that it wasn't good enough for MO, but if people agree I can try there.

Comment: I agree with Eric.

Comment: Ok. Will close this question. Others please vote to close - I suggest 'off topic' ;-)

Comment: @David: I've closed the question. However it'd be good to edit your question to include a link to the MO question once you post it there.

Comment: Done, Zev. Two answers there an counting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd find more arithmetic geometers in MO than here, I reckon. Here's my two cents' worth. There are moduli problems in arithmetic geometry as well, so it's not too surprising that you'd find stacks there as well: in fact, Behrang Noohi has an interesting short article in which he showed how to view the quotient of the upper half plane by the action of a discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ as a stack (http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~noohi/papers/WhatIsTopSt.pdf). There is also an interesting paper of Henri Gillet, "[Arithmetic Intersection Theory on Deligne-Mumford Stacks](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.1424)", that may be of interest.